# VScode does not recognize any of the conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, virtual-environment

I used to be able to choose the appropriate Anaconda environment from Command Palette however when I open the VScode today I should have messed up the configuration somehow that it does not really show any conda environment (even the base).
[image]

When I type `conda env list` in the anaconda prompt it shows the list of all the environments correctly. I am using Windows 10 and I am wondering what could possibly go wrong here since I cannot really use VSCode anymore (It will not recognize any environment or any package).

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Have you updated the VSCode? And can you try to add the environments manually?

Comment: Yes, I have updated VSCode (and then this happened). Manually it works. However, how can I do something that it detects automatically?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode does some changes in the interpreter. So maybe the update clears the cache of the interpreter which storage early.

> A VSCode internal storage is introduced which will now store the
> interpreter settings in the workspace & workspace folder scope. i.e
> workspace settings are no longer stored in
> settings.json/.code-workspace, but an internal storage.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments) for more details.